# AWK pipe output to SED to replace

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to replace a string using AWK pipe out to SED

```
grep pdo_user /html/data/_default_/configs/application.ini | awk '{print $3}' | sed -i 's/$1/"username"/g' /html/data/_default_/configs/application.ini
```

but found string is not replaced

Output for

`grep pdo_user /html/data/_default_/configs/application.ini | awk '{print $3}'`

is

`"root"`

Any tips on that?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: But `$3` from `AWK` is a string `"root"` which I need to replace each time with `"username"`

Comment: I suggest to replace `'s/$1/"username"/g'` by `'s/'"$1"'/"username"/g'`. `$1` should not contain any special characters that sed could interpret as commands.

Comment: Still `$1` is not passed to sed

Comment: Please add output of `grep pdo_user /html/data/_default_/configs/application.ini | awk '{print $3}'` and `echo "$1"` to your question.

Comment: OP updated with grep to awk piping output

Comment: Remove last `/html/data/_default_/configs/application.ini` from your command line. Output should show `"username"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127838/discussion-between-jacktheknife-and-cyrus).

Comment: I think you want something like `sed 's/'$(awk '/pdo_user/{print $3}' /path/to/application.ini)'/"username"/' /path/to/application.ini` ? Good luck.

Comment: @JackTheKnife: Do you want to replace in every line which contains somewhere `pdo_user` string `root` in column three by string `username`?.

Comment: @Cyrus Correct - I'm searching for `pdo_user` which contains some string at 3r position (in this case string is `"root"`) and I want to replace that string with `"username"` (both strings contains double quotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution based on Shelter's tip using AWK and SED

```
sed -i 's/'$(awk '/pdo_user/{print $3}' /path/to/application.ini)'/"username"/' /path/to/application.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use awk and mv:

```
awk '/pdo_user/ && $3=="\"root\"" {$3="\"username\""}1' /path/to/application.ini > /path/to/application.tmp
mv /path/to/application.tmp /path/to/application.ini
```

Comment: But `pdo_user` may be different than `"root"` which was only in my case but example is good enough to replace without the statement `&& $3=="\"root\""`